# house hold wiring for two way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, home-automation, bulb

how to install a wiring where I can have two switches the two switches will turn on a bulb

I have to turn on the light if any of the switch is on and I have to turn off the light if any of the switch is turned off

can you suggest me a way to install such a mechanism thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a 3 way switch (2 ea 3 way switches) check out [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93036/3-way-switch-issue), or search the site there are probably over a hundred with examples Of proper wiring. The basics are if the light is off flip one of the switches the light is now on. Flip one switch the light is off. There are also digital models that can dim, or turn off from both locations one switch is a master or the control the second switch is a slave or remote.

Comment: Footnote for non-US readers: In some parts of the world the switches required are described as 2-way switches (2 switches controlling one light). Technically they are single pole dual throw (SPDT) switches but only electronic engineers use that kind of name. You also need an extra "traveller" wire between the two switch locations (for common ways of wiring this up).

Comment: Thanks@RedGrittyBrick. I did not know other country's called them 2 way.+