# Bathroom light not working but extractor fan is

Tags: bathroom, light-fixture, transformer

My bathroom light is not working but the extractor fan via the same cord fitting is. I replaced the cord fitting and checked there's current running through both wires when it is turned on.

I then checked the transformer in the halway which controls power to the light and fan. I checked with a voltage screwdriver and it picks up voltage to both the fan wires when the light is switched on but only the brown wire on the light, not the blue wire.

I asume there's an issue with the transformer as, is it easy to fix? It looks like an old model so not sure I could get a replacement, it says 'vent axia selv 12' on the outside.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your lightbulb need replacing?

Answer (score 1):

SELV 12 means it is a 12-volt device.

Your "voltage screwdriver" is not suitable for testing low voltages like this.

The wiring should be as follows

[image]

Note this shows a main bathroom-light as well as a low-voltage light inside the fan unit.

Your pull-cord switch operates at 240VAC.

The Transformer does not supply power to the main bathroom-light. Only to the SELV light inside the fan-unit (where applicable).

The usual reason for lights not lighting is that the light-bulb needs replacing. You don't say whether you have replaced the bulb or tested it.

You can check the 12v connections using a more suitable [voltage tester](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/90038/2815) (with a 12V capability but safe for 240VAC)